# 301 redirection - front page to subdirectory

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I needed to redirect my od domain to a new one. All paths are same on both domains except the front page, which needed to be redirected from www.mydomain.com to www.mydomain2.com/newpath. I googled and came up with this code which works. My question is if it is valid and if all pageranks will be transfered without problems. Thank you

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} domain\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
Rewriterule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain1.com/folder/ [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain1.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code should work but it can be fine tuned a bit. Please consider this refactored code:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.com$ [NC]
Rewriterule ^$ http://www.domain1.com/folder/ [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.domain1.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```